# user_login_submit() is not working in Drupal 8 with AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, drupal, drupal-8

I am working with AngularJS, REST API & Drupal 8. I am able to pass values between AngularJS and PHP, drupal user authentication is working, but user_login_submit() is not working.
In console, it shows 500 Internal Server Error

Please take a look of code

```
    if(isset($_POST)){
    // Getting posted data and decodeing json
        $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $form_state['uid'] = \Drupal::service('user.auth')->authenticate($username, $password); 
        $uid = $form_state['uid'];
        if($uid != '' || $uid != NULL){
            $user = user_load($uid);
            user_login_submit($form, &$form_state);
            return 'Successfully logged in';
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

MUST BE

```
$username = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
```

Hope it works.